# Filter out integers in an array of int and symbols

Tags: ruby, hash, integer, symbols

I've seen lots of post using .kind_of Integer or .integer? and these work if the input is an int or a string but I have a hash with values of symbols and integers and I want to iterate through the values and flag when I come across an integer.

More specifically I'm doing a tic tac toe game and on my board each position will have an in (position number) or an :x or :y because it has been played by that player.  To check if the game has tied I want to try to iterate over  these values and if I find an int then I know the board isn't "full".

Comment: Show us what the board looks like and we'll help you.  When you ask a question on SO it's better to have "here's my input" and "here's my desired output".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `is_a?(Integer)` like this:

```
{ :x => 1, :y => 'foo' }.each do |key, value|
  puts value.is_a?(Integer)
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  That does actually work, I thought it was just like the others but it does seem to be working.  Thanks so much :)

Comment: `is_a?` is actually an alias of `kind_of?`, so both should work. It's defined on the `Object` class, so it can be called on an object of any type. [`integer?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-integer-3F) doesn't work because it's defined on the `Integer` class, so you cannot call that method on strings and symbols.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try something like this to check for symbols:

```
case parameter
  when Symbol
    # process Symbol logic
  when String
    # process String logic
  when Integer
    # process Integer logic
  else
    # some other class logic
end
```